# Spring boot google search result

Tags: spring-boot, google-search-api

Is it possible to search something in google from spring boot application and store the google search result in spring boot application to manage the search result? Thank you

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback